# Why Integer doesn't solve null String

Tags: java

Integer class contains some method to convert String into Integer:

1. `Integer.parseInt(null);` Parameter: String Return: int, so I expected when parameter is null this throw NPE
2. `Integer.valueOf(null);` Parameter: String Return: Integer,so I expected when parameter is null this should return null. But this precondition was wrong and I ask why there is no such method which can handle this situation ?

Comment: The Javadoc says: "NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable integer". Is that what you are getting?

Comment: It's not a behaviour you should generally need to rely on (returning null on a null parameter), so it's not usually an issue. If you do need to rely on it, just create a utility method that wraps it and deals with null in the desired way?

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo nope. My question is why there is some new method which can handle with null String. It is so difficult create if(value == null) return null else retun valueOf(value) ?

Comment: So you're saying you just want to know why it doesn't already exist for you rather than asking how to solve a technical problem?  There's no answer other than "The Java developers didn't do it.  Because they didn't."  Flagging for closure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The folks at Sun who implemented Integer (a `long` time ago :) ) probably were not thinking of databases when they wrote that method. Except when dealing with database data, or rare cases where you are trying to explicitly represent "unknown" with null, null is usually a sign of something gone terribly wrong. In general, it's a good idea to raise an exception as soon as there is a problem. (a [Fail fast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) design)

If you have ever spent time hunting down a segmentation fault in C that is due to a string value longer than the memory you supplied for it (which then overwrote some program code or other data) you will have a very good appreciation of how bad it is to not fail when something has gone wrong.

Since the time of Java 1.0, interaction with databases in java has become extremely common so you might be right to suggest that there should be a method to handle this. Integer is a final class so if you build your own Integer like class you will loose autoboxing, so this probably does require a change to the language by oracle.

Basically, what you observed is the way it is for now, and someone will have to pay you to code around it :)

Answer (score 11):

`null` is not a valid representation of integer number. `Integer.parseInt()` requires that the string be parsed is a vaild representation of integer number.

**[Integer.parseInt()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)**

```
  public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
440                 throws NumberFormatException
441     {
442         if (s == null) {
443             throw new NumberFormatException("null");
444         }
```

[Integer.valueOf(str)]](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) 

// which inviokes Integer.parseInt(Str) to return an Integer instance.

```
  public static Integer valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException
569     {
570         return new Integer(parseInt(s, 10));
571     }
```

Comment: I disagree I use Integer because I need to handle with null value. When I dont want I use int

Comment: ... you disagree with the java specs?

Comment: I think what PremGenError means by integer is the mathematical entity, not an object of the `Integer` class. :)

Comment: @Jeff you are right. thus i said `integer number` in my answer. also note the lowercase i :)

Comment: @hudi Integer can be null but you cannot obtain a int representation of null. How would you represent a null value? If you think of -1, this approach would be invalid in any domain where negative values make sense. Anyway you could write your own parseInt method. In my application we return -1 when we try to parse a null String, but that's a convention we have agreed to (we, the developers for this particular application).

Comment: @SamDufel I dont say that. I miss some method which can handle null String without exception.  It is so difficult create if(value == null) return null else return valueOf(value) ?

Comment: The question is about `valueOf` and not `parseInt`. Been edited to add `valueOf`.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau check my edit. Integer.valueOf() infact calls's Integer.parseInt()

Comment: @PremGenError my question was not about these two method. I know how they works. My question is about some third method which should solve null String without exception

Comment: @hudi unfortunately ther is no such method in API AFASIK. However, as i said in my answer `null` is not a valid rep of a numeric value.`java.Lang.Integer` though being an Object was mainly introduced to make use of primitives in java collections. thus i think allowing null in parsing integers doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, @hudi, but is this what you are looking for?

```
public Integer valueOf2( String inputString ) {
    return (inputString == null) ? null : Integer.parseInt(inputString);
}
```

Comment: yea I write this in comments but my question is why there is no such method in Integer class ?

Answer (score 0):

@hudi, what about this?

[IntegerConverter](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils//api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/converters/IntegerConverter.html)

I've never used it, but it looks like you can specify a default value if there is a conversion error.  I know it is a pain to include another jar in your project just for this;  It would be nice if there was something standard.